# How do I make a custom html element focusable with Voiceover on mobile Safari?

Tags: mobile-safari, accessibility, voiceover

I am on mobile Safari (Safari on my iPhone) and I noticed that Voiceover does not focus on an element that has a tabindex set to 0 (the element is a div). What needs to be done to make the div get focus while testing with voiceover? Will adding an aria role make a difference?

Swiping right does not make VO announce the video element. This appears to be a bug with Safari and VO on a mobile device while rendering a tag.

Comment: Why would a div ever need to get "focus" (focus in this case meaning that the div requires some sort of user interraction so is the current reciever to keyboard events).  As long as the contained content is read off you should be good to go.  It doesn't need "focus".  Instead of asking this question, why not explain what you're trying to do, and we can suggest an alternative...  Or is your original issue that the content is not read out in voiceover?

Comment: @ChrisCM It's good to make sure questions are on point, but yours is not a particularly productive comment.  The primary reason *I* often need to put focus on an element is for custom input types that still need to remain useful accessibility-wise.  There are always multiple ways to do things - but sometimes the neatest/maintainable solution isn't immediately useful for vision-impaired.

Comment: If you believe my comment was suggesting the question was off point, you have misunderstood my comment.If you believe your last sentence was an original thought in comparison to my comment, you have also misunderstood my comment.It's funny to me you suggest a comment is unproductive, and then you essentially re-word it.Also, if you look at the additional comments, you will see that the description provided based on my comments about focus, my suspsicion was correct, the OP does not need user interaction, but rather something is not being announced.I consider this a very valuable clarification.

Answer (score 0):

First, you misunderstand what focus means in this context.  For something to be announced in Voiceover it does not require "focus".  Focus means something much more specific, in particular an object with focus is the starting point for the bubbling of keyboard events, among other things.

The type of "focus" you're referring to is only a concern in the world of accessibility, and this is the ability of an AT to render(read to the user) the content in the proper order.  It is likely that the issue you are experiencing is a result of the content within the DIV and not the DIV itself.  As such, no matter how much effort you put forth attempting to get this DIV "focused" the content within will not announce properly.

You mention that it "won't announce the video element".  ATs have issues with embedded video players and such.  What you can do is provide some offscreen text to describe the content of the video, or provide a link to an audio only version of the content.  You can either do this within the same div, or within its own div.